# Jenkins bitbucket-webhooks Plugin wrong url

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, webhooks

I've created a Post Webhook in our bitbucket server to our jenkins server.
At jenkins side I installed the Bitbucket plugin and checked "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket".

So now if I push sth to my Bitbucket repo, jenkins receives the payload and checks if a job matches.
But it has an invalid url so the match will never work:

```
Nov 27, 2018 7:54:18 AM FINE com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.BitbucketJobProbe
Trying to match ssh://git@someBitbucket:7999/proj/someRepo.git<-->http://localhost:7990/proj/someRepo
```

Can anyone tell me why the job repository url is checked against a localhost url?